# Disable authentication on Blazor Server page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a Blazor Server application, and I need to set up a page that's viewable without being domain-authenticated through Windows authentication, and that doesn't prompt first for credentials. I've seen a lot of suggestions regarding the use of `[AllowAnonymous]`, which doesn't appear to work correctly, and the only other idea that seems common is disabling global authentication entirely and using `[Authorize]` attributes on every single page separately, which is obviously not an ideal solution.

Is there any way to mark a single Blazor page as viewable without authentication?

Comment: `[AllowAnonymous]` is  the officially recommended method, You need to check if there is anything wrong in your code.

Comment: This is a problem present even in default projects. Run `dotnet new blazorserver -o <name> -au windows` and add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to a page; it still won't work as intended.

Comment: MayBe you can refer to this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/248835/allow-anonymous-user-on-a-blazor-page.html)